# How to hide divs using a Google Map

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-maps

I'm creating a website using HTML, CSS and jQuery, in which there is a Google Map (using Google Maps API V3), some markers on the map, and some divs at the bottom of the page which are initially hidden. What I would like to do is make each of these divs visible if the corresponding marker is within the current viewport of the map (ie. if I can see the marker, I wanna see the div, too, and if I don't see the marker, I don't wanna see the div). Any help will be appreciated.

These are the divs, whose visibility I would like to toggle:

```
            <div class="bot-item r1">
                <h1>Athens</h1>
                <p>The capital city of Greece</p>
            </div>
            <div class="bot-item r2">
                <h1>Washington, D.C.</h1>
                <p>The capital city of the USA</p>
            </div>
            <div class="bot-item r3">
                <h1>Rome</h1>
                <p>The capital city of Italy</p>
            </div>
            <div class="bot-item r4">
                <h1>Berlin</h1>
                <p>The capital city of Germany</p>
            </div>
            <div class="bot-item r5">
                <h1>Paris</h1>
                <p>The capital city of France</p>
            </div>
            <div class="bot-item r6">
                <h1>Warsaw</h1>
                <p>The capital city of Poland</p>
            </div>
```

I store all the markers (6 markers total) in an array, and I've used the following code to try to achieve what I wanted. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. (I attached the code below to the 'idle' event of the Google Map.)

```
        for(var i = 0 ; i <= 5 ; i++){
            var j = i + 1;

            if(map.getBounds().contains(markers[i].getPosition()) == true){
                $(".r" + j).show();
            }
            else{
                $(".r" + j).hide();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I just edited my question, and I hope that I helped you understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

To detect whether or not markers are visible you should use [`map.getBounds()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map%20%60map.getBounds%28%29%60), then for each markers you should test if current map bounds contains our marker by using : [`contains()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds%20%60contains%28%29%60) method and [`Marker.getPosition()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker%20marker).

I have created a JSFiddle to show you a working example : http://jsfiddle.net/glafarge/mbuLw/

[image: Google Maps - Visible Markers In Bounds]